# Using cards for list items

Tags: bootstrap-4

In boostrap 4, "well" is replaced by "card".

However, I don't get the same result here :

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="card">...</li>
    <li class="card">...</li>
</ul>
```

Here I just replaced "well" with "card". Obviously it seems we don't use card this way. But I cannot find how to get the same result reading the docs.

With bootstrap 3 and "well", we had a nice box with a grey backgroud, for each list item.  And every list item was wrapped in default padding/margins.

What is the boostrap 4 equivalent ?

Comment: `class="card bg-light"` adding `bg-light` should give the same visual effect as a well

Comment: Thanks, I did this : `<ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item bg-light">`.

Comment: For spacing betwee the list items, is there a way with boostrap 4 ?     For now I can only do it by adding a custom margin rule for the <li>.

Comment: bootstrap has a `utilities` column that gives you access to `flex` classes [view here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/). On your `<li class="list-group-item bg-light"> `you can add the class `my-1` up to `my-5` which applies margin to the top and bottom of the element or you can do `mx-1` to `mx-5` which applies margin to the left and right or you can do just `m-1` to `m-5` which gives margin on all sides. `1-5` being he available sizes

Comment: Excellent !  You can post an answer and I'll accept it.  THANKS!

Comment: awesome. Will do!